# Ignore error on specific character in .vimrc

Tags: vimscript, error

I'm using the accepted answer in [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/27340/30351) post, and as such, tried using the character `*` in my `.vimrc`, but it seems to generate `E20: Mark not set` as error, which i want to ignore (only for the instance when the `*` is used).

I'm aware of the `silent!` command, which ignore errors on a specific command, but i believe this might not work in this case.

Any way to do this?

Comment: Er, comment it out? (Double quote starts a comment)

Comment: I would, but i need it as it is (as what the intended purpose of the post i linked explain) if it's commented, then it wouldn't be useful :) @D.BenKnoble

Comment: For clarification on why i want this not commented: this [post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27339/make-fold-feature-act-like-emacss-org-mode-fold) should explain it. @D.BenKnoble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just start lines with `*` in your vimrc and have Vim ignore them. `*` is not really a comment character, it's a valid command.

Under `'nocompatible'` (which is most surely the mode under which everyone is using Vim these days), `:*` is a shortcut to `:'<,'>`, which is the range of lines comprising the last Visual selection. (See [`:help cpo-*`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#cpo-star), keeping in mind that under `'nocompatible'` this option is not set.)

Instead of trying to get Vim to accept your special syntax, just adapt it so that it will work inside comments (actual Vimscript comments.)

You can do that by changing your matching pattern to:

```
'\v^\s*("\s*)?\zs\*+'
```

This will accept an optional `"` (plus whitespace) before the stars.

In that case, you would write:

```
" * first header
(Some Vimscript here.)
" ** second header
(More text.)
" *** third header
(Test.)
```

But then, consider whether this is actually that much of an enhancement over the default [`foldmethod=marker`](https://vimhelp.org/fold.txt.html#fold-marker) settings, under which you would write the following to accomplish the same folding configuration:

```
" first header {{{1
(Some Vimscript here.)
" second header {{{2
(More text.)
" third header {{{3
(Test.)
```

Comment: so does that mean there no way to truly change/disable the shortcut `cpo-star`? at least on specific filetype... (I don't mind using your proposed solution, but being able to do this would be really nice).

Comment: So i tried doing [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27367/changing-cpoptions-only-work-in-commandline) but it seems that, while it worked (for removing the star from cpoptions) the previously mentioned error `Mark not set` still occur...

Comment: Uhhh... It's actually `set cpo+=*` with a literal `*` and not `s` or the letters in `star`. `:help cpo-s` will tell you it's about setting options on buffers. But if you have `set cpo+=*` then `:*` behaves the same as `:@` which is to execute a register as an Ex command, e.g. `:@"` for the default register. So a `*` by itself will complain about no register instead of no mark... But it will still complain.