# Changing cpoptions only work in commandline

Tags: vimscript, command-line

So i tried to change the setting from `cpoptions`, so i did:

```
set cpoptions=aABceF
```

on the commandline, where `s` for the star is missing (on purpose) and it seems to work fine but only if i do it in the commandline. If i use it in my `.vimrc`, nothing happen, and doing:

```
set cpoptions?
```

In the commandline after opening vim show:

```
set cpoptions=aABceFs
```

Where `s` isn't missing as intended (which worked only in the commandline as shown above).

How can i make this work in my `.vimrc` too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting

```
set cpoptions=aABceF
```

At the end of my `.vimrc` worked (instead of at the start).

Comment: Do you have `set nocompatible` in your vimrc? If you do, that command will reset `'cpoptions'` to the default... So any setting of `'cpoptions'` before that line will be overwritten.

Comment: You can always try `:verbose :set cpoptions?` to see where it was reset

Comment: I don't :) using latest Vim from git, so i believe it's already using `nocompatible` by default, especially since i have a `.vimrc`. @filbranden

Comment: How can i make it so it's set only in my `.vimrc`? or so the above line in my `.vimrc` take precedence over the result from `:verbose :set cpoptions?`? @ChristianBrabandt

Comment: @NordineLotfi I don't understand? `:verbose :set cpoptions?` queries only where the option was last set/changed. It does not change anything

Comment: It's possible something in your vimrc is sourcing something that sets `'nocompatible'` (or resets `'cpoptions'`), see [How do I debug my vimrc file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/18609) if you'd like to figure out where it's being clobbered.